# "SharePointFullPage" app can't be removed

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I made a SPFx web part using supportedHosts "SharePointFullPage"
After a while I removed it from the tenant and the site because I made a totaly new one with new identity.

Now it is showing in the choices of apps on new page and there is no why to remove it.
The "Delete from site" does nothing.
PowerShell `Get-PnPApp` does not show it either

Any idea how to get rid of it?
Thank you
[image]
The green box is the current valid solution.
the red is the one I can't get rid of. It is not listed in the site or the tenant.

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: To help you better, can you provide more screenshots on this issue?